# Why the weight vector is perpendicular to the displacement of the object being moved by the tension force in the conical pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, energy, work

Can someone explain why, in the conical pendulum, the weight vector is perpendicular to the displacement of the object being moved by the tension force in the system? I understand that the tension force does no work on the object because it makes a 90-degree angle to the displacement. But it is yet unclear to me why the weight does not also work on the object.

Answer (score 0):

Weight is a vertical force. The conical pendulum moves in a horizontal circle. Horizontal is perpendicular to vertical.

Comment: Should we not consider that the object that is being moved in the pendulum, like a bob, has a displacement that is tangent to the circular path just like how we considered it when we say that the 'tension force does no work because the displacement is tangent to the circular path, and hence making a 90-degree angle'?

Answer (score 0):

Both tension and weight are perpendicular to the displacement, which indeed is along the tangent to the circular path at any time. In 3D geometry you can have more than one perpendicular to a given line and these perpendiculars can have different directions. In plane geometry all perpendiculars to agiven path are parallel to each other but in 3D this is not so. [image]

In the figure included, both PR and QR are perpendicular to TS. And so is PQ. Just imagine PQ translated so that it crosses the horizontal plane at R rather than Q.
Now consider ST as the tangent to the circular trajectory, at a given moment. PQ will be the direction of the tension and PQ the direction of the weight. QR will be the radius of the circle. Lots of perpendiculars to that tangent.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the setup we are talking about:
[image]

We know there is equilibrium in the z-direction:

$$\sum F_z=0=mg-T\cos(\theta) \text{  } \rightarrow mg=T \cos(\theta)$$

We also know it is going through centripetal motion in the xy-plane:

$$ma=m \frac{v^2}{r}=T\sin(\theta)$$

From here you can derive all of the E.O.M.